# customized pagination in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have codeigniter applicatin which have pagination code that work like a charm. Pagination allow the visitor to select how much records he would like to see per page. Now, I would like to add the following:

displaying X to Y from total of Z records.

Now, Z is easy...i have that solved. Can anyone tell me how could I achive this?

Here is the function that i have:

```
  public function displayAllUsers() 
   { 

        if ($this->uri->segment(3) !="") { 
        $limit = $this->uri->segment(3); 
        } else { 
        $limit = 10; 
        } 

        $offset = 4; 
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(4); 
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset); 
        $data['users'] = $this->backOfficeUsersModel->get();
        $totalresults = $this->db->get('back_office_users')->num_rows();

        $this->session->set_userdata('totalresults', $totalresults);

        //initializing & configuring paging
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('/backOfficeUsers/displayAllUsers/'.$limit.'/');
        $config['total_rows'] = $totalresults;
        $config['per_page'] = $limit;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap pagination"><ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a href=# style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#258BB5;">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

       //....irelevant content.....

    } // end of function displayAllUsers
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be that hard. In fact, it's kinda obvious how you can get the value for X and Y if you understand pagination.

First of all, the difference between X and Y will of course be equal to `$limit` - 1. The value of X should be equal to the variable, `$offset`, plus 1 (Offset generally starts from 0 not 1). And from there, I'm sure that you understand that Y is equal to `$offset + $limit`.

```
$X = $offset + 1;
$Y = $offset + $limit;
```

In case, you're at the last page, you'll want to make sure you have the right value for Y. You'll need to check the total rows you grab from the database, if it's less than the limit per page, then change it to something like this

```
if (fetched_rows < $limit)
{
    $Y -= ($limit - fetched_rows); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Kemal. I have 12 records. I display 10 records per page. On the first page, using the code above i have now: Showing 1 to 11 from total of 12. Which is wrong. On next page, it shows:Showing 11 to 21 from total of 12  Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: @Zoran My bad. I didn't think through everything. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I changed my per page number to 4 so I can see better what i got. After updating the code, only one small problem remain to be solved: So on page first page, 4 records displayed, read this:Showing 1 to 5 from total of 12 (should be 1 to 4? or no?) Next page read this:Showing 5 to 9 from total of 12 and the last page read this:Showing 9 to 13 from total of 12 which is wrong, I have total of 12 records.

Comment: after changing the above code with: 
$x = $offset + 1;
                     
                     $y = $offset + $limit;
                     
                     if ($recordsCount < $limit){
                        $y -= ($limit - $recordsCount); 
                     } 
works like a charm. Thanks a ton.